# CSS - Allow image to overflow container but not show a horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: css

I am using the Bootstrap framework and I am absolutely positioning an image in the right column. The idea is to have the image be cut off on the right side on smaller screen sizes and on larger screen sizes the entire image would be visible. This is working correctly except for that on smaller screen sizes there is a horizontal scrollbar due to the overflow. Is it possible to accomplish this without having a horizontal scrollbar while at the same time not cutting the image off where it overflows?

```css
div {
  position:relative;
}
.image-container {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:-200px;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu venenatis dolor. Duis ornare orci id nulla faucibus, vitae tristique lectus fringilla. Phasellus malesuada sem sit amet nisl maximus, sed accumsan ante suscipit. In aliquam tempor lorem eu aliquam. Donec auctor ut felis tincidunt malesuada. Mauris ut velit a quam tempus ultricies. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur malesuada velit libero, at venenatis metus ultricies a. Cras sit amet blandit ante. Nullam malesuada dignissim mauris, pretium lobortis tellus pellentesque sed.</p>
      <p>Proin tristique non mauris eu varius. Etiam dictum mattis eros, sed euismod nisl pulvinar vitae. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean at dui lorem. Donec faucibus arcu sit amet turpis commodo accumsan eget vel arcu. Nulla maximus, lectus eu lobortis laoreet, turpis arcu auctor turpis, a aliquet magna ante at ipsum. Vestibulum eu aliquet augue. Curabitur feugiat metus vel euismod bibendum. Duis non cursus sapien. Suspendisse eget tortor ac velit tristique iaculis at eu lectus. Etiam dapibus justo sed placerat eleifend. Curabitur tincidunt, dui non suscipit tincidunt, est libero faucibus lacus, et fringilla diam urna sit amet dolor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus porttitor erat vel facilisis interdum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-6">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try with `overflow-x: hidden` so there's no horizontal scroll/scrollbars

Comment: You have in `class="image-container"` `-200px` that is overflow container. And `img` should be some `width`.

Answer (score 0):

add class `img-fluid` to your image. That means `width: 100% & height: auto`. This class is given to the tags like image and video to be responsive.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

.image-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu venenatis dolor. Duis ornare orci id nulla faucibus, vitae tristique lectus fringilla. Phasellus malesuada sem sit amet nisl maximus, sed accumsan ante suscipit. In aliquam tempor lorem
        eu aliquam. Donec auctor ut felis tincidunt malesuada. Mauris ut velit a quam tempus ultricies. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur malesuada velit libero, at venenatis metus
        ultricies a. Cras sit amet blandit ante. Nullam malesuada dignissim mauris, pretium lobortis tellus pellentesque sed.</p>
      <p>Proin tristique non mauris eu varius. Etiam dictum mattis eros, sed euismod nisl pulvinar vitae. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean at dui lorem. Donec faucibus arcu sit amet turpis commodo accumsan eget vel arcu. Nulla maximus, lectus eu lobortis laoreet,
        turpis arcu auctor turpis, a aliquet magna ante at ipsum. Vestibulum eu aliquet augue. Curabitur feugiat metus vel euismod bibendum. Duis non cursus sapien. Suspendisse eget tortor ac velit tristique iaculis at eu lectus. Etiam dapibus justo sed
        placerat eleifend. Curabitur tincidunt, dui non suscipit tincidunt, est libero faucibus lacus, et fringilla diam urna sit amet dolor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus porttitor erat
        vel facilisis interdum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-6">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x300" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```